# How to aggregate data based on conditions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Having the following table:

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| categ. | elem. | atr_1 | atr_2 |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|      1 |     1 |     2 |     1 |
|      1 |     2 |     2 |     2 |
|      2 |     3 |     1 |     3 |
|      2 |     4 |     1 |     3 |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
```

...I'm trying to obtain the resulting table showing the best element per category:

```
+--------+--------+
| categ. | elem.  |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |      2 |
|      2 |      3 |
+- ------+--------+
```

In order to determine which element is the 'best' per category the system needs to check which element has the max(atr_1) per category. If more than one element is retrieved will look at max(atr_2) of the retrieved elements. If more than one element is retrieved one of the resulting ones will be randomly assigned to the category.

I'm not able to figure out how to aggregate and use the conditional statements in order to compose the required query. Any suggestion?

I'm using standard SQL in Google BigQuery.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BigQuery'ish way to solve this would just use aggregation:

```
select (array_agg(t order by atr_1 desc, atr_2 desc limit 1))[ordinal(1)].* except (atr_1, atr_2)
from t
group by categ;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY atr_1 DESC, atr_2 DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT category, element
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE 
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT(categ, elem) ORDER BY atr_1 DESC, atr_2 DESC LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY categ
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row categ   elem     
1   1       2    
2   2       3
```